# ionic Cannot find type definition file for '@types'

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

---

I upgraded my ionic 6 project to use angular 3, everything works on debug mode, but when I try to compile for production: 'ionic build --prod or ionic cordova build anrdoid --prod', I am getting the following output:

---

```
ionic-app-scripts build --prod
[11:37:38]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4 
[11:37:38]  build prod started ... 
[11:37:39]  clean started ... 
[11:37:39]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[11:37:39]  copy started ... 
[11:37:39]  deeplinks started ... 
[11:37:40]  deeplinks finished in 1.34 s 
[11:37:40]  ngc started ... 
[11:39:07]  typescript error 
            Cannot find type definition file for '@types'. 

[11:39:07]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[11:39:07]  Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript 
Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript
    at errorCheckProgram (/Users/shanon/zoro/ionic_grid/manage-plyzw/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:119:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shanon/zoro/ionic_grid/manage-plyzw/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:89:21)
    at step (/Users/shanon/zoro/ionic_grid/manage-plyzw/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/shanon/zoro/ionic_grid/manage-plyzw/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/shanon/zoro/ionic_grid/manage-plyzw/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
ionic-app-scripts build --prod exited with exit code 1.
```

***Ionic Info
my project info is fllow,i upgreage the Ionic CLI to latest,and i try to many times,it's not work. please help me,thanks!

---

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.14.1 (/Users/shanon/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.0, (and 30 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/shanon/zoro/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   NodeJS            : v12.18.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.6
   OS                : macOS Big Sur
```

***package.json
this is my ionic project package.json.

---

```
{
  "name": "myapp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.12",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-minimize": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@jiguang-ionic/jpush": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.1.9",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.9.0",
    "ion-multi-picker": "^2.1.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.10",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jpush-phonegap-plugin": "3.6.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "socket.io": "^2.4.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "videogular2": "^6.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.12",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@faus said This error showed up after upgrading @ionic/app-scripts: 3.2.3 to latest version 3.2.4. But i dont upgragding @ionic/app-scripts: 3.2.3 to latest version 3.2.4,and it's not working.

i downgrading @ionic/app-scripts: latest version 3.2.4 to 3.2.3, it's not working.
so,i use @faus method,it's working,so superise!

**it's fixed method fllow this:**[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426772/cannot-find-type-definition-file-for-types)

I did not downgrade to fix it

I added

"types": [],

into

"compilerOptions"

in tsconfig.json file and the error was gone.

Now my tsconfig.json file looks like this:

"compilerOptions": {
"types": [],  <== fix added here <==
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"declaration": false,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
"dom",
"es2015"
],
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5"
}